# Missing CvViewFrameListener2 interface

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I'm new to Android and OpenCV, and I try to follow [this simple tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#hello-opencv-sample). I got stuck at implementation of `CvViewFrameListener2` interface:

> Defines that your activity implements CvViewFrameListener2 interface and fix activity related errors by defining missed methods.

Eclipse shows an error, that the `CvFrameListener2` cannot be resolved to a type. It seems like this interface doesn't exist in the library.

I load OpenCV4Android version 2.4.5. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Seems like the interface name is misspelled in the tutorial. Instead of `CvViewFrameListener2` I used `CvCameraViewListener2` and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I m sure this is late. But I faced this problem too, here my workaround

make sure you have imported the openCV sdk as a library project and linked to your project.

[image]

Hope this help

also I used this project from github for face recognition [face recognition](https://github.com/ayuso2013/face-recognition)

and this link to download OpenCV 2.4.6 android sdk 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.6/OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk-r2.zip/download